# why c++ pthread exited by itself without process crash?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, kernel, pthreads

I have a process which uses almost 16 threads. On of the thread id getting exited by itself after working for some time (please note process didn't crash). I am not sure how to look for reasons for thread exiting ? I tried using print statement but that doesn't seems to help. Tried capturing through gdb didn't help. If this is some sort of memory corruption then the process should crash and core file should have tell everything (most of the time) but process remains running just the thread exiting is making my job difficult..

Can you please suggest some way to debug this issue ?

-Arpit

Comment: Without viewing the code it is very difficult to answer the question stated in the title. GDB (like any other debugger) has many options to help, but again, it depends on the code you have.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, can you please provide pointers which gdb options can be helpful. The code is huge spread across multiple files and I don't know which code block has the problem (I am trying to find that only)

Comment: Is it always the same thread routine that exits?  If so put breakpoints on all of its `return` statements and maybe also on `pthread_exit`.

Comment: @G.M.   Yes, Same thread is getting exit after running some time.. I am not using pthread_exit() as this process a daemon process. The whole process is running under while (1) neither I am using any exit() function. hence I am not getting the clue where it's getting exit.

Comment: Well, you are using `pthread_exit` -- just not directly.  When a thread routine (as passed to `pthread_create`) issues a `return`  statement `pthread_exit` will be called for that thread.  If you check the man page for `pthread_create` it states `"The new thread terminates in one of the following ways: [...] It returns from start_routine().  This is equivalent to calling pthread_exit(3) with the value supplied in the return statement."`.  So setting a breakpoint on it could provide some useful information.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how to look for reasons for thread exiting

There are only two ways that I can think of for this to happen:

1. The thread function returns
2. Something the thread function calls executes `syscall(SYS_exit, ...)`

You can use `(gdb) catch syscall exit` and then `where` to find out where this is happening.

If `where` shows something similar to this:

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007ffff7bc3556 in __exit_thread () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/exit-thread.h:36
#1  start_thread (arg=0x7ffff781c700) at pthread_create.c:478
#2  0x00007ffff7905a8f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:97
```

then you have case 1, and you need to step through your thread function to find out where it is returning (https://rr-project.org/ may help a lot).

If instead you see something like this:

```
(gdb) where
#0  syscall () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/syscall.S:38
#1  0x0000555555554746 in do_work () at t.c:9
#2  0x0000555555554762 in fn (p=0x0) at t.c:15
#3  0x00007ffff7bc3494 in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff781c700) at pthread_create.c:333
#4  0x00007ffff7905a8f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:97
```

then the culprit is whatever routine called `syscall`.